# How can I model my clothes ecommerce product in mongodb database with variants?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, e-commerce

I am currently making ecommerce application in Next.js with the help of mongodb database in the backend side. I just want to keep mine record of the products like tshirts, hoodies and jackets with various variants like they vary in colors and size.

Can somebody help be desigining the product model for storing my product details with **ratings**, **features**, **variants**, **skus**, **brandname**, **categories**, **multiple images**, etc.
How can I store multiple images of different variants of a product in mongodb?
Please someone help me!!!

I am stuck with this here. I am just a beginner now .[Needs to store various images and variants of the product in mongodb database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aGY6.png)

I tried to insert different document for all the variants of the products like this: [my product collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWs1E.png)

I want to know how can I do that by putting all the variants in the same document and can insert multiple images of different variants.